# How to use ST_Distance to get places near POSTGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a POSTGIS database:

```
     name     |                    geom                    | latitude | longitude 
--------------+--------------------------------------------+----------+-----------
 Burger King  | 0101000000728A8EE4F2EF344076711B0DE0154A40 |  52.1709 |   20.9373
 Kumpir Kebab | 01010000002C6519E25807354023DBF97E6A144A40 |  52.1595 |   21.0287
```

The task is, I will enter my location(longitude latitude), the query should return distance between me and these two places. How should I write the query?

Comment: Check out st_point and st_distance - you should be able to assemble a query with those.https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html

Answer (score 1):

As you already said yourself, you have to use [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) with the `geom` column and a given point. The entered point can be created using [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html), e.g.

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (name text, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO t 
VALUES ('Burger King','0101000000728A8EE4F2EF344076711B0DE0154A40'),
       ('Kumpir Kebab','01010000002C6519E25807354023DBF97E6A144A40');
```

Distance in the unit of measurement of your SRS

```
SELECT name, ST_Distance(geom,ST_MakePoint(52.17,21.02)) AS dist
FROM t ORDER BY dist;

     name     |       dist        
--------------+-------------------
 Kumpir Kebab | 44.03917603611585
 Burger King  | 44.11190451680816
(2 Zeilen)
```

Distance in meters

```
SELECT 
  name, st_astext(geom),
  ST_Distance(geom::geography,ST_MakePoint(20.9542,52.1801)::geography) AS dist
FROM t
ORDER BY dist;

     name     |       st_astext        |     dist      
--------------+------------------------+---------------
 Burger King  | POINT(20.9373 52.1709) | 1544.19617066
 Kumpir Kebab | POINT(21.0287 52.1595) |  5588.8104441
(2 Zeilen)
```

**Note**: if the geometry column contains the same coordinates as the lat and long columns, one of them is superfluous ;)